# Q# Could Not Find Workspaces due to DotNet Core

Tags: visual-studio-code, quantum-computing, q#

I get error for every parts of the code since I think net core problem.

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(59,5): The "ProcessFrameworkReferences" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Frameworks, Version=5.6.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[image: Q#]

Comment: Please provide more information on your issue!

Comment: It's a know issue. They need to publish an update for the new .net core:
https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/issues/434

Comment: Thanks! I am waiting next update for new .net core.